# ffmpeg server vs darwin stream server

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, rtsp, darwin

I am looking for video stream server for mobile,and find dss and mfpeg server.
is anyone know the difference between dss and ffmpeg server? which one is recommended?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you need a server with a lot of community coverage, use vlc. It is uses live555libs (live555 has its seperate streaming server too)
As for the other too, i found that DSS was better. You can lookup how to install and configure but troubleshooting can get real annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Of course DSS is preferred.
1. Easy to use
2. Better performance
3. More readable & stable code...

ffmpeg server is usually used by hackers to experiment some new protocols, codecs, etc.